# OneDrive upload image to a folder Rest API

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin, onedrive

I am using OneDrive rest apis to create folder and upload images to that folder. I can successfully create the folder but image upload call always giving the following error

> {
>      "error": {
>         "code": "request_body_too_large", 
>         "message": "The request entity body is too large."
>      }
>   }

Here is my code:

var uri = string.Format("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/{0}/files?access_token={1}", folderData.id, authToken);

var file = new OneDriveMetaData { name = backupcontent.FileName };

var multipartContent = new MultipartContent();

multipartContent.Add(metaData);

multipartContent.Add(backupcontent.Content);

var metaData = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(file), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Length”, bytearraylength);

HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/related; boundary=A300x”);

HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + backupcontent.FileName + "\"”);

await BaseClient.PostAsync(uri, multipartContent);

Comment: what is the size of your image?

Comment: abut 150-250 kb

Comment: are you using xamarin? it is not clear from your question.

Comment: Yes Xamarin forms

Comment: May be the problem related to this:<p>
This file is too big
If you use Internet Explorer 10 or a recent version of other popular web browsers, you can upload files to OneDrive that are up to 10 GB in size. If you use an older web browser, you can't upload files larger than 300 MB.<p>https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fix-problems-uploading-files-on-the-OneDrive-website-9afcc4a0-e344-4bc9-9c9d-59d3e802247e  Can you try to upload smaller file?

Comment: What is 'bytearraylength' set to?

Comment: You really should use the OneDrive API (https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm) instead of the Live Connect API you're referencing here. With the OneDrive API, you wouldn't need to construct the Multipart MIME body, you can simply do a PUT request to `https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/filename.jpg:/content` and be done.